# Julia, how to install the latest development version?

Tags: julia

I want to install the latest dev version of julia for development purposes. I'm not sure how to install it and configure vscode to use it. How can I do it in pop os 22.04?

Comment: that depends on your os and processor architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest beta version here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/releases/tag/v1.9.0-beta4

If you want the latest dev version on `master` follow instructions to build it here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#building-julia

It's probably easier to uninstall the release version to make it easier to get VS Code to recognize the dev version, and alias the dev build to `julia` or move it to wherever you store applications. VS Code probably also has a place to select the Julia compiler/interpreter (idk which it is) like it has for Python

[image]

Comment: Thank you! how do you alias the dev build to `julia`?